# How to Convert Get Method to Post Method in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<form action="<? bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">

 <select name="page_id" id="page_id">
 <?php
    $related = get_posts( 
        array( 
            'post_type' => 'Episode',
            'category__in' => wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID ), 
            'numberposts'  => -1, 
            'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ) 
        ) 
    ); 

if( $related ) { 
foreach( $related as $post ) {
setup_postdata($post);?>
<option value="<? echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></option>

<?php }}?>

 </select>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
 </form>
```

Hello Guys! how to convert it to post method? what i mean is when selecting the posts it will automatically going to that specific post? anyone help me im very stress!?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be in the form. In  just add a link:

```
<a href="<?php get_permalink() ; ?>">
```